# ReactJS server-side rendering, setTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, settimeout, server-side-rendering

On my ReactJS App I used `setTimeout` to defer some Redux action:

```
export const doLockSide = (lockObject) => (dispatch) => {
  const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: CONSTANTS.TOPICS_SET_CURRENT_TOPIC_LOCKED_SIDE,
      payload: { id: lockObject.topicId, side: lockObject.side, locked: false }
    });
  }, lockObject.unlockTimeout);

  dispatch({
    type: CONSTANTS.TOPICS_SET_CURRENT_TOPIC_LOCKED_SIDE,
    payload: { id: lockObject.topicId, side: lockObject.side, timerId, locked: true }
  });
};
```

The `lockObject` comes from the server, so this code is a part of async Redux actions chain. It worked fine, but when I tried to make this functionality to be a part of server side rendering process, it broke the App. I understand the difference between Browser and NodeJS runtime environments and the difference between its implementations of `setTimeout`. Specifically my `timerId` could not be processed by Node due to it's an object, while my Redux reducer treats it as an integer. But the main problem is that during server side rendering Node fires `setTimeout` callback on the server side...

**The question**. I have some redux-based proccess that should be deferred in some cases including the App start. How can I do it satisfying the requirement of server-side rendering?

Comment: You should be waiting for all the data to return and then send the response to the client.
Have a look at the examples shown in redux page here: https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html#async-state-fetching

Comment: @MatanBobi All necessary data is being fetchet during server-side rendering, it's not an issue. The problem is to defer some action on client side based on this data. Client should run a timeout after it is rendered. And I can't call `setTimeout` during rendering because it will lead to server-side timeout.

Comment: What is the meaning of the timeout? what is it for? if you have all the data already when using the ssr, build the whole page, there's no need to wait. A purpose for the timeout would help understanding i guess.

Comment: @MatanBobi I need to temporary block some functionality on the UI based on some conditions. And then I need to unblock it after `unlockTimeout` have passed.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I was able to apply the following approach.

**1)** Push the deferred action data into some special storage in case of server-side rendering, and run it "as is" in case of Browser:

```
import { _postRender } from '../utils/misc';

const doLockSideUI = (dispatch, lockObject) => {
  // the body of previous version of doLockSide inner function
  const timerId = setTimeout(() => {/*...*/}, lockObject.unlockTimeout);
  dispatch(/*...*/);
};

export const doLockSide = (lockObject) => (dispatch) => {
  if(typeof window === 'undefined') { // server-side rendering case
    _postRender.actions.push({
      name: 'doLockSide',
      params: lockObject
    });
  }
  else { // Browser case
    doLockSideUI(dispatch, lockObject);
  }
};
```

Where `utils/misc.js` has the following entity:

```
// to run actions on the Client after server-side rendering
export const _postRender = { actions: [] };
```

**2)** On the server I've imported that `_postRender` object form `utils/misc.js` and pushed it to `render` parameters when all redux-store data dependencies had been resolved:

```
const markup = renderToString(/*...*/);
const finalState = store.getState();
const params = { markup, finalState, postRender: { ..._postRender } };
_postRender.actions = []; // need to reset post-render actions
return res.status(status).render('index', params);
```

`_postRender.actions` has to be cleaned up, otherwise `_postRender.actions.push` from p.1 will populate it again and again each time the Client had been reloaded.

**3)** Then I provided my post-render actions the same way as it is done for preloaded state. In my case it is `index.ejs` template:

```
<div id="main"><%- markup %></div>
<script>
  var __PRELOADED_STATE__ = <%- JSON.stringify(finalState) %>;
  var __POST_RENDER__ = <%- JSON.stringify(postRender) %>;
</script>
```

**4)** Now I need to call my `__POST_RENDER__` actions with given params. For this purpose I updated my root component's did-mount hook and dispatch an additional action which handles the post-render action list:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('The App has been run successfully');
  if(window.__POST_RENDER__ && window.__POST_RENDER__.actions.length) {
    this.props.dispatch(runAfterRender(window.__POST_RENDER__.actions));
  }
}
```

Where `runAfterRender` is a new action that is being imported from `../actions/render`:

```
import { doLockSide } from './topic'

export const runAfterRender = (list) => (dispatch) => {
  list.forEach(action => {
    if(action.name === 'doLockSide') {
      dispatch(doLockSide(action.params));
    }
    // other actions?
  });
};
```

As you can see, it's just a draft and I was forced to import `doLockSide` action from p.1 and call it explicitly. I guess there may be a list of possible actions that could be called on the Client after server-side rendering, but this approach already works. I wonder if there is a better way...